# How to display my string date into readable date format in PHP

Tags: php

I have a date in string "20150617"
that means 17 June 2015

How I can convert the String into
"17-JUN-2015" using PHP Code.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
<?php    
echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime('20150617'));
?>
```

[date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)  [strtotime](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Dont forget to set the default time http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
<?php
echo date('d-M-Y',strtotime(20150617))
?>
```